# c# json object won't deserialize

Tags: c#, json, class, deserialization

i'm trying to use the nba api to return me a json object.

```
{
"resource": "commonteamyears",
"parameters": {
    "LeagueID": "00"
},
"resultSets": [
    {
        "name": "TeamYears",
        "headers": [
            "LEAGUE_ID",
            "TEAM_ID",
            "MIN_YEAR",
            "MAX_YEAR",
            "ABBREVIATION"
        ],
        "rowSet": [
            [
                "00",
                1610612737,
                "1949",
                "2017",
                "ATL"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612738,
                "1946",
                "2017",
                "BOS"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612739,
                "1970",
                "2017",
                "CLE"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612740,
                "2002",
                "2017",
                "NOP"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612741,
                "1966",
                "2017",
                "CHI"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612742,
                "1980",
                "2017",
                "DAL"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612743,
                "1976",
                "2017",
                "DEN"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612744,
                "1946",
                "2017",
                "GSW"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612745,
                "1967",
                "2017",
                "HOU"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612746,
                "1970",
                "2017",
                "LAC"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612747,
                "1948",
                "2017",
                "LAL"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612748,
                "1988",
                "2017",
                "MIA"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612749,
                "1968",
                "2017",
                "MIL"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612750,
                "1989",
                "2017",
                "MIN"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612751,
                "1976",
                "2017",
                "BKN"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612752,
                "1946",
                "2017",
                "NYK"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612753,
                "1989",
                "2017",
                "ORL"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612754,
                "1976",
                "2017",
                "IND"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612755,
                "1949",
                "2017",
                "PHI"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612756,
                "1968",
                "2017",
                "PHX"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612757,
                "1970",
                "2017",
                "POR"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612758,
                "1948",
                "2017",
                "SAC"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612759,
                "1976",
                "2017",
                "SAS"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612760,
                "1967",
                "2017",
                "OKC"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612761,
                "1995",
                "2017",
                "TOR"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612762,
                "1974",
                "2017",
                "UTA"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612763,
                "1995",
                "2017",
                "MEM"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612764,
                "1961",
                "2017",
                "WAS"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612765,
                "1948",
                "2017",
                "DET"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610612766,
                "1988",
                "2017",
                "CHA"
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610031,
                "1946",
                "1946",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610029,
                "1948",
                "1948",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610025,
                "1946",
                "1949",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610034,
                "1946",
                "1949",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610036,
                "1946",
                "1950",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610024,
                "1947",
                "1954",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610027,
                "1949",
                "1949",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610030,
                "1949",
                "1952",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610033,
                "1949",
                "1949",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610037,
                "1949",
                "1949",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610023,
                "1949",
                "1949",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610026,
                "1946",
                "1946",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610028,
                "1946",
                "1946",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610032,
                "1946",
                "1948",
                null
            ],
            [
                "00",
                1610610035,
                "1946",
                "1946",
                null
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

}

the json it gives me back is giving me a headache using the built in vs paste to class i get this as my classes

```
public class Parameters
{
    public string LeagueID { get; set; }
}

public class ResultSet
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> headers { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> rowSet { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string resource { get; set; }
    public Parameters parameters { get; set; }
    public List<ResultSet> resultSets { get; set; }
}
```

now the only thing i want back is the rowset which has the teamID and abbreviaton in it. unfortunately i have no clue how to proceed with the given class.

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: Please add what error are you getting and what have you tried already.

Comment: Btw: a json format that is an arbitrary collection of headers etc with a rows collection is frankly horrible. That kinda defeats the objective of well defined data formats. IMO should be `"TeamYears": [ { "leagueId":"foo", "teamId":123, ...}, {...}, {...}]`

Comment: What do you mean with "won't deserialize"? Using NewtonSoft.Json, a simple `var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourjson);` works absolutely fine, and in the property `root.resultSets[0].rowSet` you find your rowsets you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("my.txt"); // I'm too lazy to escape
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var data = obj.resultSets.Single(x => x.name == "TeamYears");
var teamIdIndex = data.headers.IndexOf("TEAM_ID");
var abbrIndex = data.headers.IndexOf("ABBREVIATION");
foreach(var row in data.rowSet)
{
    var id = row[teamIdIndex];
    var abbr = row[abbrIndex];
    Console.WriteLine($"{id}: {abbr}");
}
```

sample output:

```
1610612737: ATL
1610612738: BOS
1610612739: CLE
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the rowSet as,

```
RootObject obj = new RootObject();
var something = obj.resultSets[0].rowSet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the format of JSON you have to work with is, ahem, somewhat unorthodox. So you will have to do some manual jiggling.

Assuming you are using JSON.Net, and you loaded all your classes, we just need to add one more:

```
public class NbaRow
{
    public string LeagueId {get;set;}
    public long TeamId {get;set;}
    public string MinYear {get;set;}
    public string MaxYear {get;set;}
    public string Abbreviation {get;set;}
}
```

Now the code would look something like:

```
var json = "... json here ...";

var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>();
var results = new List<NbaRow>();
foreach(var item in root.resultSets.rowSet)
{
   results.Add(new NbaRow{
    LeagueId = Convert.ChangeType(item[0], typeof(string)),
    TeamId = Convert.ChangeType(item[1], typeof(long)),
    MinYear = Convert.ChangeType(item[2], typeof(string)),
    MaxYear = Convert.ChangeType(item[3], typeof(string)),
    Abbreviation = Convert.ChangeType(item[4], typeof(string))
   });
}
```

Note: this assumes the order of headers doesn't change. Use @MarcGravell's answer, if the headers can change.